# Shell script to loop over files with same names but different extensions

Tags: linux, bash, shell

For example say I have:

```
filename1.ext1 filename1.ext2 filename2.ext1 filename2.ext2
```

I need to write a shell script to feed these files into a program like so:

```
program filename1.ext1 filename1.ext2
program filename2.ext1 filename2.ext2
```

Additionally the `.ext1` files must be entered first and the `.ext2` files second.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Call it as `program filename1.*` and `program filename2.*`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

anubhava's solution is excellent if, as they do in your example, the extensions sort into the right order.  For the more general case, where sorting cannot be relied upon, we can specify the argument order explicitly:

```
for f in *.ext1
do 
  program "$f" "${f%.ext1}.ext2"
done
```

This will work even if the filenames have spaces or other difficult characters in them.

Answer (score 0):

Script **program**:

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in "$@";do
echo "$file"
done
```

Run program:

```
path/to/program filename1.*
path/to/program filename1.* filename2.*
path/to/program filename1.ext1 filename1.ext2
etc...
```

Comment: Sorry, what does the @ symbol do?

Comment: @ethanpowell it is to get all element from array. `${arr[@]}` is all element of array `$arr`.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to solve this problem.

If you want to handle `your_script foo.a foo.b bar.a bar.b` (pairs of arguments in sequence):

```
#!/bin/bash
while [[ $# -gt 2 ]]; do
  program "$1" "$2"
  shift 2
done
```

But if you want to take in a list of matching names, you don't even need to take in the second set of extensions. Call this like `your_script foo.a bar.a` or `your_script *.a`:

```
#!/bin/bash
for FILE1; do                   # same as: for FILE1 in "$@"; do
  FILE2="${FILE1%.ext1}.ext2"   # removes .ext1 if it exists and adds .ext2
  program "$FILE1" "$FILE2"
done
```

Note that the above doesn't handle missing files. You can use `if [[ -f $FILE2 ]]; then program; fi` to test that the corresponding file exists.